# I wish to return the same dataframe with duplicates identified

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

I understand how I may retrieve a new dataframe (df) of TRUES & FALSES for duplicate identification, but I am hoping for roughly the exact same df returned with a new column that identifies if the row is a duplicate or not. It could be the identifier appended to the previous df or a whole new df.

Please note that my df has over 20 million records. Also note that my df has only two columns. One test will look for duplicates on only one column. Another test will look for duplicates on the combination of columns.

Thank you.

**reproducible data**

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(A = rep(1:3, each=4), B = rep(1:4, each=3), C = rep(1:2, 6), key = "A,B")

#     A B C
#  1: 1 1 1
#  2: 1 1 2
#  3: 1 1 1
#  4: 1 2 2
#  5: 2 2 1
#  6: 2 2 2
#  7: 2 3 1
#  8: 2 3 2
#  9: 3 3 1
# 10: 3 4 2
# 11: 3 4 1
# 12: 3 4 2
```

Comment: try `df$new_col1 <- duplicated(df) | duplicated(df,fromLast=TRUE)` and  `df$new_col2 <- duplicated(df$col_to_check) | duplicated(df$col_to_check,fromLast=TRUE)`

Comment: That is super-slick. Thank you so much.
Below is some of the code I created:
DT <- data.table(A = rep(1:3, each=4), B = rep(1:4, each=3), C = rep(1:2, 6), key = "A,B")
DT$new_col1 <- duplicated(DT)
# new_col1 is a column of TRUEs & FALSEs to identify exactly what is a duplicate.
DT$new_col2<-duplicated(DT$A)
The first example looks for duplicates for both columns. The 2nd example looks for duplicates only in column A.

Please excuse my sloppy editing.

Comment: glad that I could help. I've edited your question with your sample data and copied your solution below.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `duplicated` on any `data.frame` :

```
DT$new_col1 <- duplicated(DT) 
DT$new_col2 <- duplicated(DT$A) 

DT
#     A B C new_col1 new_col2
#  1: 1 1 1    FALSE    FALSE
#  2: 1 1 2    FALSE     TRUE
#  3: 1 1 1     TRUE     TRUE
#  4: 1 2 2    FALSE     TRUE
#  5: 2 2 1    FALSE    FALSE
#  6: 2 2 2    FALSE     TRUE
#  7: 2 3 1    FALSE     TRUE
#  8: 2 3 2    FALSE     TRUE
#  9: 3 3 1    FALSE    FALSE
# 10: 3 4 2    FALSE     TRUE
# 11: 3 4 1    FALSE     TRUE
# 12: 3 4 2     TRUE     TRUE
```

As you're using `data.table` you might want to use `data.table` syntax (thanks @Frank):

```
DT[,new_col1:= duplicated(.SD)][,new_col2:= duplicated(A)]
```

FYI `data.table` has its own method for `duplicated` that can also be used as follows:

```
duplicated(DT, by="A")
# [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

see `?data.table:::duplicated`